# What does this flowchart control statement mean?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, controls, flowchart

[flowchart while loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZYC9.png)

In the picture above, the control statement is "loopCount < ? 10". What is the correct control statement of this one if written in code? (code should be written in a while loop, java)

"while(loopCount<=10)" or "while(loopCount==10)"?

What does "< ?" mean?

Comment: that is a simple conditional statement, hence the possible results: true and false. IF loopCount < 10 THEN perform the true part ELSE perform the false part

Comment: I don't know what the "?" means. Looks like a mistake / formatting error in the flow chart. About the solution: Think about what your proposed while statements mean. You can read them as if they are almost English and then reason. Hint: Both are wrong. The flowchart asks you to check if loopCount is less than 10, not less-or-equal or equal to 10.

Answer (score 1):

> *Q: What does `loopCount < ? 10` mean?*

It looks to me like a typo.  It would make more sense if it was written as:

```
loopCount < 10 ?
```

Or in plain English as *"is loopCount less that 10?"*.

The entire flowchart<sup>1</sup> can written in Java as a `while` loop, or a `for` loop.

However, neither of your attempts is exactly correct.  See Jesper's comment.

What you need is a Java loop that performs the "output" with `loopCount` values 1 through 9 inclusive; i.e. nine times.

---

<sup>1 - You can't translate the flowchart boxes and lines individually and assemble them into valid / working Java.  A literal translation would require `goto` statements for some of the lines, and Java doesn't support that.  (Old-school FORTRAN, COBOL and BASIC did!)  Instead, you have to extract the *meaning* of the flowchart, and *write* Java code that does the same thing.</sup>